# Is there a better way to do this? without having to declare the ones that are checked false

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a Hospital Charge Menu, i'm adding the services charges if they are checked and in another if value in numeric up down is more then 1. But i wanna leave the ones that are checked and do all the sum, if i dont declare the ones checked false the loop stays infinite

```
Do While (chkMedicine.Checked Or chkRehab.Checked Or chkSurgery.Checked Or chkRehab.Checked)

            If (chkMedicine.Checked) Then
                chkMedicine.Checked = False
                If (nudMedicine.Value > 0) Then
                    TotMed = +Medicine * nudMedicine.Value
                Else

                    TotMed = +Medicine
                End If
            ElseIf (chkSurgery.Checked) Then
                chkSurgery.Checked = False
                If (nudSurgery.Value > 0) Then
                    TotSurg = +Surgery * nudSurgery.Value
                Else
                    TotSurg = +Surgery
                End If

            ElseIf (chkLabs.Checked) Then
                chkLabs.Checked = False
                If (nudLabs.Value > 0) Then
                    TotLabs = +Labs * nudLabs.Value
                Else

                    TotLabs = +Labs
                End If
            ElseIf (chkRehab.Checked) Then
                chkRehab.Checked = False
                If (nudPhysRehab.Value > 0) Then
                    TotRehab = +PhysicalRehab * nudPhysRehab.Value
                Else

                    TotRehab = +PhysicalRehab
                End If
            End If

        Loop
        TotalServices = (TotMed + TotSurg + TotLabs + TotRehab)
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are using a loop at all.

Comment: Yep, just saw the error, i put the loop to get all the sum, because i forgot to add `TotalServices = (TotMed + TotSurg + TotLabs + TotRehab)` at the end of the function. If i remove the loop it suppose to do the same and leave the ones that are checked untouched

Comment: Deleted the while loop and its not adding all the services, it's only adding one

Comment: Why not set the minimum value of your numeric up down to 1?  that way you no longer need to check the values of those and simplify your decisions

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have more than one thing checked, remove the `ElseIf`s and change them to all separate `If` statements.  This way you'll enter the block for EACH one that is checked.

Also your [Compound Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements) are not doing what you think they are as the `+` should be BEFORE the `=`, not after.  The way you had it written you were replacing the total, not adding to the total.

```
If (chkMedicine.Checked) Then
    chkMedicine.Checked = False
    If (nudMedicine.Value > 0) Then
        TotMed += Medicine * nudMedicine.Value
    Else

        TotMed += Medicine
    End If
End If

If (chkSurgery.Checked) Then
    chkSurgery.Checked = False
    If (nudSurgery.Value > 0) Then
        TotSurg += Surgery * nudSurgery.Value
    Else
        TotSurg += Surgery
    End If
End If

If (chkLabs.Checked) Then
    chkLabs.Checked = False
    If (nudLabs.Value > 0) Then
        TotLabs += Labs * nudLabs.Value
    Else
        TotLabs += Labs
    End If
End If

If (chkRehab.Checked) Then
    chkRehab.Checked = False
    If (nudPhysRehab.Value > 0) Then
        TotRehab += PhysicalRehab * nudPhysRehab.Value
    Else

        TotRehab += PhysicalRehab
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.Minimum` property of the `NumericUpDown` controls to 1 so you don't have to check the value for 0.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'You would probably want to set these properties at design time
    nudMedicine.Minimum = 1
    nudSurgery.Minimum = 1
    nudLabs.Minimum = 1
    nudPhysRehab.Minimum = 1
End Sub
```

Every time a check box changes or an up/down changes your calculate method will be called. This is accomplished by writing a method with same signature as the matching event procedure and including the controls in the Handles clause.

```
Private Sub AnyCheckBoxChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkMedicine.CheckedChanged, chkRehab.CheckedChanged, chkSurgery.CheckedChanged, chkLabs.CheckedChanged
    CalculateCharges()
End Sub

Private Sub AnyNumericUpDownValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nudMedicine.ValueChanged, nudSurgery.ValueChanged, nudLabs.ValueChanged, nudPhysRehab.ValueChanged
    CalculateCharges()
End Sub
```

Your Calculate method does not need a loop. Just check which boxes are checked and calculate.

```
Private Sub CalculateCharges()
    Dim TotMed As Decimal
    Dim Medicine As Decimal = CDec(25.0)
    Dim TotSurg As Decimal
    Dim Surgery As Decimal = CDec(1000)
    Dim TotLabs As Decimal
    Dim Labs As Decimal = CDec(200)
    Dim TotRehab As Decimal
    Dim PhysicalRehab As Decimal = CDec(300)
    Dim TotalServices As Decimal
    If chkMedicine.Checked Then
        TotMed = Medicine * nudMedicine.Value
    End If
    If chkSurgery.Checked Then
        TotSurg = Surgery * nudSurgery.Value
    End If
    If chkLabs.Checked Then
        TotLabs = Labs * nudLabs.Value
    End If
    If chkRehab.Checked Then
        TotRehab = PhysicalRehab * nudPhysRehab.Value
    End If

    TotalServices = TotMed + TotSurg + TotLabs + TotRehab
End Sub
```